# Does macOS Big Sur mounts sparse bundles served from a network share as Read-Only?

Tags: network, big-sur, sparsebundle

I have a few writable sparse bundles that are located on a network share. I can mount and modify the content of these bundles from any pre-BigSur macOS release. However, after upgrading one of my macs to Big Sur it started mounting the same bundles in a read-only mode.

Surprisingly, when I copy over a bundle locally to that Big Sur mac and mount it from any local storage (internal SSD or a USB or TB drive) it appears to be writable.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here are some troubleshooting details:

```
% hdiutil attach /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle -verbose -debug -readwrite
calling DIHLDiskImageAttach with 
image-options:
debug: true
quiet: false
drive-options:
main-url: file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
read-write: true
verbose: true
agent: hdiutil
2020-11-29 14:01:14.487 hdiutil[14882:1376009] DIHLDiskImageAttach: input dictionary {
    agent = hdiutil;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" =     {
    };
    "image-options" =     {
    };
    "main-url" = "file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/";
    quiet = 0;
    "read-write" = 1;
    verbose = 1;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.488 hdiutil[14882:1376009] DIHLDiskImageAttach: newImagekeys = {
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.488 hdiutil[14882:1376009] DIHLDiskImageAttach: creating DIHelperProxy
2020-11-29 14:01:14.488 hdiutil[14882:1376009] with dictionary: {
    agent = hdiutil;
    debug = 1;
    "drive-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "image-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "main-url" = "file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/";
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    quiet = 0;
    "read-write" = 1;
    verbose = 1;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.488 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy alloc]
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy alloc] returning self 0x7fdb93605260, retainCount 1
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376009] DIHLDiskImageAttach: running DIHelperProxy
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] detaching thread
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] setting up server
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.489 hdiutil[14882:1376018] XPC: creating helperconnection connection
2020-11-29 14:01:14.522 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy threadSetupServer] exiting
2020-11-29 14:01:14.522 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] entry (spawn version)
2020-11-29 14:01:14.522 hdiutil[14882:1376018] launching helper tool at "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/diskimages-helper".
2020-11-29 14:01:14.526 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy threadLaunchToolAuthenticated] exiting (spawn version)
2020-11-29 14:01:14.526 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] calling waitForHelperDone
2020-11-29 14:01:14.553 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] entry, helper
2020-11-29 14:01:14.554 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.554 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] starting operation with helper
2020-11-29 14:01:14.554 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy sendOperationToHelper] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.554 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy connectToFramework] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.578 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: initialize
Initializing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2020-11-29 14:01:14.581 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.584 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] updateImageAndDriveDictionaries: before update _imageOptions: {
    "enable-keychain" = 1;
    writeable = 1;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.584 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] updateImageAndDriveDictionaries: update _imageOptions: {
    "enable-keychain" = 1;
    writeable = 1;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.584 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] _driveOptions: {
    autodiskmount = 1;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.584 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: initializing framework
2020-11-29 14:01:14.585 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] {
    agent = hdiutil;
    "allow-tty-prompt" = 1;
    "auto-fsck-failure-override-type" = callback;
    "auto-open-ro-root" = 0;
    "auto-open-rw-root" = 0;
    "auto-stretch" = 0;
    "bundlebs-checkpointing" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localcloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-localfdcount" = 6;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonflush" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonidle" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotecloseonsleep" = 0;
    "bundlebs-remotefdcount" = 3;
    "burn-no-underrun-protection" = 0;
    "burn-synthesize-content" = 1;
    "bzip2-level" = 0;
    "callback-with-sla" = 1;
    debug = 1;
    "disable-encrypted-images" = 0;
    "disable-kernel-mounting" = 1;
    "disable-owners" = 0;
    "drive-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "enable-owners" = 0;
    "hfsplus-stretch-parameters" =     {
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-block-size" = 4096;
        "hfsplus-stretch-allocation-file-size" = 8388608;
        "hfsplus-stretch-threshold" = 524288;
    };
    "idle-timeout" = 15;
    "ifd-format" = UDZO;
    "ifd-segment-size" = 0;
    "iff-format" = UDZO;
    "iff-fs" = "HFS+";
    "iff-layout" = GPTSPUD;
    "iff-source-owners" = auto;
    "iff-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    "iff-temp-sparse-band-size" = 20480;
    "iff-temp-use-rw-if-possible" = 1;
    "iff-usehelper" = 1;
    "ignore-bad-checksums" = 0;
    "image-options" = {length = 42, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d0080000 00000000 ... 00000000 00000009 };
    "main-url" = "file:///Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/";
    "mount-attempted" = 1;
    "mount-point" = "/Volumes/";
    "mount-private" = 0;
    "mount-required" = 1;
    "mount-type" = in;
    "nbi-spotlight-indexing" = 0;
    operation = DIHelperAttach;
    "pthread-reader-cap" = 4;
    quiet = 0;
    "read-write" = 1;
    "skip-auto-fsck-for-system-images" = 1;
    "skip-previously-verified" = 1;
    "skip-sla" = 0;
    "skip-verify" = 0;
    "skip-verify-locked" = 0;
    "skip-verify-remote" = 1;
    "sparsebundle-compactonidle" = 0;
    "suppress-uiagent" = 1;
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
    "use-keychain" = 1;
    verbose = 1;
    "zlib-level" = 1;
}
DILoadDriver: checking for disk image driver
DILoadDriver: DI_kextExists() returned 0x00000000 (0)
DIIsInitialized: returning NO
2020-11-29 14:01:14.589 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.589 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] imageURL file:///Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
2020-11-29 14:01:14.589 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] shadowURL (null)
2020-11-29 14:01:14.589 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] sectionStart (null) sectionLength (null)
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
skip-permissions-check: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe directory, not a valid image file.
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe: got bundle
CFBundle 0x7fac4b4133a0 </Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle> (not loaded)
band-size: 8388608
bundle-backingstore-version: 1
diskimage-bundle-type: com.apple.diskimage.sparsebundle
size: 50000020480
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion: 6.0
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score 1000 for file:///Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: perm is 0
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
bs-no-follow: true
skip-permissions-check: true
use-filename-for-prompt: Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
bs-no-follow: true
skip-permissions-check: true
use-filename-for-prompt: Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setNoFollow: setting _noFollow to 1
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 0
CBundleBackingStore::setURL entry
CBundleBackingStore::setURL CFURLStat passed
CBundleBackingStore::setURL fPath is /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
CBundleBackingStore::isRemote: returning TRUE
CBundleBackingStore::setURL got unique identifier
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setURL returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::setSecurityToken entry
CBundleBackingStore::setSecurityToken proxy encoding not supported
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setSecurityToken returned 0
copyInfoPlist: fcntl(F_OPENFROM, Info.plist) passed
copyInfoPlist: total read 498 bytes
band-size: 8388608
bundle-backingstore-version: 1
diskimage-bundle-type: com.apple.diskimage.sparsebundle
size: 50000020480
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion: 6.0
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: getting kDIBackingStoreSizeKey
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: dfLength 50000020480
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: getting kDIBackingStoreBandSizeKey
CBundleBackingStore::processBundle: _bytesPerBand 8388608
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: processBundle returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::isRemote: returning TRUE
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _maxOpenBands is 3 entries
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: kMaxAsyncCloses is 16 
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnSleep is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnIdle is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTableCloseOnFlush is no
CBundleBackingStore::processOptions: _bandTable initialized
CBundleBackingStore::setPermission entry inPerm = 0
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: setPermission returned 0
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: returning 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 0
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 0
2020-11-29 14:01:14.624 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: resolving file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/ returned 0
2020-11-29 14:01:14.624 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] -checkForPreviouslyAttachedImage: imageUID (
    "d872415235:i18759"
) shadowUID (null)
2020-11-29 14:01:14.625 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] DIHelperAttach: performOperation: resolving disk image
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
image-path: /Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
enable-keychain: true
writeable: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
image-path: /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
enable-keychain: true
writeable: true
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe directory, not a valid image file.
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe: got bundle
CFBundle 0x7fac4b4133a0 </Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle> (not loaded)
band-size: 8388608
bundle-backingstore-version: 1
diskimage-bundle-type: com.apple.diskimage.sparsebundle
size: 50000020480
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion: 6.0
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score 1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: perm is 3
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Volumes/Household/DATA/Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
use-filename-for-prompt: Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
writeable: true
enable-keychain: true
bs-no-follow: true
image-path: /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
use-filename-for-prompt: Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
writeable: true
enable-keychain: true
bs-no-follow: true
image-path: /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Volumes/.../Template_Encrypted50GB.sparsebundle/token
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000002 -> 0x00000026 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 35
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 35. 
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: openSecurityToken() failed. 35
CBundleBackingStore::newWithCFURLandToken: returning 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 35
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 35. 
DIResolveURLToDiskImage: resolving backing store/file encoding failed. 35. 
2020-11-29 14:01:14.650 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] calling home {
    "error-code" = 35;
    "status-stage" = attach;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.650 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: attach
Attaching…
Error 35 (Resource temporarily unavailable).
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2020-11-29 14:01:14.658 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit 0
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] calling home {
    "status-stage" = cleanup;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] entry
status proc called: cleanup
Finishing…
myStatusProc: returning 0 
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] [DIHelperOperator frameworkCallbackWithDictionary] exit 0
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] DIHelperAttach performOperation: returning 35
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376032] -decrementBackgroundThreadCount: _backgroundThreadCount is now 0.
2020-11-29 14:01:14.659 diskimages-helper[14885:1376029] DIHelper _report_results: reporting {
    payload =     {
    };
    "result-code" = 35;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] reportResultsToFramework: proxy has finished operation
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] reportResultsToFramework: results are: {
    payload =     {
    };
    "result-code" = 35;
}
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] reportResultsToFramework: _threadResultsError is 35
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] reportResultsToFramework: disconnecting from helper.
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] disconnectFromHelper: terminating proxy
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376018] -[DIHelperProxy(Thread) waitForHelperDone]: done waiting. _helperDone=1
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy waitForHelperDone] releasing connection
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] disconnectFromHelper: terminated proxy
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376014] [DIHelperProxy disconnectFromHelper] exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] after waitForHelperDone
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] waiting for task to terminate to avoid zombies
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] DIHelper: terminateHelper: entry.
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] entry
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] releasing connection
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] -DIHelperAgentMaster terminateUIAgentConnection.
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] marking _frameworkDisconnected
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] preparing to act like a daemon.
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376030] [DIHelper frameworkConnectionDied] exiting
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376029] -setCanTerminate: main thread can exit
2020-11-29 14:01:14.660 diskimages-helper[14885:1376029] helper: child_after_exec returning 0
2020-11-29 14:01:14.661 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] helper exited
2020-11-29 14:01:14.661 hdiutil[14882:1376018] [DIHelperProxy workerThread] exiting
2020-11-29 14:01:14.661 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy performOperationReturning] returning 35
2020-11-29 14:01:14.661 hdiutil[14882:1376009] DIHLDiskImageAttach: DIHelperProxy returned 35
2020-11-29 14:01:14.661 hdiutil[14882:1376009] [DIHelperProxy dealloc]
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 35
hdiutil: attach failed - Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: That type of network share? Have you tried mounting it from the command line in **Terminal**? Example: `hdiutil attach /path/to/filename.sparsebundle -readwrite`

Comment: @user3439894, no. Just by browsing to the network share with Finder and mounting the bundle by a double-click. The network share is an SMB share where I have read-write access.

Comment: In your comment to me when you said "no. " I'm assuming you hadn't tried the _command line_ in **Terminal**, but will your try it and let me know if it mounts as _writable_?

Comment: @user3439894, correct. When I use a command line like: `% hdiutil attach /Volumes/Share/my_bundle.sparsebundle -readwrite` - I get: `hdiutil: attach failed - Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: @user3439894, btw, while the "resource temporarily unavailable" in the command line, I can mount it via Finder just fine (but only in ReadOnly mode).

Comment: AndreyKornich, I can not replicate your issue. From **macOS Big Sur** I can mount a **.sparsebundle** on an **SMB** _share_ as _Read/Write_ both from **Finder** and **Terminal** using the `hdiutil` _command_. The only thing I can suggest at the moment is to check the permissions all around.

Comment: @user3439894, if i do the same (via Finder) mounting of the bundle from the same share using the very same user account and password but from a mac with Catalina on it - the bundle is mounted as ReadWrite. I can also write into or create files within the same network share (side-by-side with the bundle) from either Big Sur or Catalina. It seems only the content of the bundle is ReadOnly when accessed from Big Sur.

Comment: BTW, i also have other bundles on the same share and they all seem to have the identical problem under Big Sur.

Comment: What happens if on **macOS Big Sur** your create a **.sparsebundle** on it, then unmount it and copy or move it to the **SMB** _share_. Can it then be mounted _Read/Write_ from **macOS Big Sur** in **Finder** and or **Terminal**?

Comment: @user3439894, yes, i already tried that with the same outcome. also, I tried placing a bundle that is RW locally on another network SMB share (hosted on FreeNAS) - same result, it is RO from Big Sur and RW from Catalina. it does look like Big Sur SMB client issue or network-shared bundle mounting issue on Big Sur.

Comment: @user3439894, any updates? I am still running into the issue. BTW, the issue I experience is remarkably similar to one discussed here: https://www.goland.org/shared_sparse_bundle/

Comment: @JoyJin, yes, `hdiutil info` does confirm read only status of the bundle. i kind of know it already :)

Comment: @JoyJin, thanks for helping! I get: `hdiutil: attach failed - Resource temporarily unavailable` while executing the command while at the same time I can still mount it via Finder (but, of course, in RO mode).

Comment: @JoyJin, both commands return nothing at all...

Comment: @JoyJin, nope, it did not improve anything. However, one more detail that I just noticed: whenever the bundle is mounted from a network share its Info properties window shows my account name with RW access but above the list of accounts - it says: "You have  custom access".

Comment: OK. Try `sudo hdiutil attach /Volumes/Share/my_bundle.sparsebundle -readwrite`?

Comment: @JoyJin, i did try that with no success. another new observation: the time machine on the Big Sur macbook can not write into existing or create a new backup bundle that is located on a proper network share (that used to work under Catalina). Most likely related to RO access to networked bundles.

Comment: Also, my Big Sur macbook's NetBios name is incorrect (I guess "randomly" stuck based on one of the network clients that last appeared on my WiFi more than 2 months ago). That wrong NetBios name stuck permanently. No matter what I do to rename it, the wrong name comes back virtually immediately. I am not sure if this is related or might cause the shared bundle access problems (doesn't SMB use NetBios?)...